# Insufficient privileges when uploading attachment to record

Tags: permissions, attachment, insufficient-privileges

User keeps getting an error of insufficient privileges when trying to upload a file as an attachment to the Product standard record. How can I grant access to upload the attachment?

Comment: have you checked that the user(S) profiles have access to the object? if yes, what about fls?

Comment: can you give a brief description of which object it is, what profile is of the user who is trying to upload attachment. Is he uploading via API or via UI?

Comment: I've edited the question with the object's name. @glls, the users have "read" access. My guess is that they need "edit" access as well?

Comment: give it a shot =P

Comment: Can't due to license limitation. But if you know it is the answer, please answer this question so I can mark it as solved! :)

Comment: did you check at a Field-Level Security for the profile? without necessarily seeting the edit to the object settings,  check the field to which you are uploading the attchment for the profile and set the field to edit & read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Attachment` object inherits its security from the parent object - so if your user only has Read access to the Product object or only Read access to the specific Product record, you will receive this error.